# bash: C:Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/bin/firebase: No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, python, firebase

```js
bash: firebase: command not found
// someone recommend me this following code
$ alias firebase="`npm config get prefix`/bin/firebase"
// i used this but after this i am getting new error like

bash: C:Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/bin/firebase: No such file or directory
```

Recently i install python and set path path for python 3 and install pip but after this iam not able run any command from terminal

Comment: If you copy and paste this path at explorer all be fine?

Comment: its not working on explorer also

Comment: `C:Users` is not a valid Windows path. It's valid on Unix, but most likely incorrect.

Comment: what is solution....?

Comment: Are you using Windows? Did you mean `C:\Users\...`?

Comment: iam suing window and getting this one
bash: C:UsersDenoversFrontendAppDataRoamingnpm/bin/firebase: No such file or directory